# Elasticsearch Sense chrome plugin disabled, need to get dsl queries written in console

Tags: elasticsearch, google-chrome-extension, elasticsearch-plugin, sense

I am running Google Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100. I previously was running the Sense (Beta) extension version 0.9.4 until Google Chrome flagged it as malware in the extensions tab. The author of Sense has removed it from the Chrome store and it has been rolled into Kibana and renamed Console.

Problem is all the queries I wrote in the Sense console are not retrievable due to the extension being disabled. Previously, every time I opened the Sense (Beta) extension, all my previous queries would be saved and re-displayed each session. I would like to find the file location where Sense stored my queries for redisplay.

I am running Windows 10. I have tried locating my saved data by going to:

```html
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

There is nothing identifiable I can find that resembles my old data. Does anyone know where I can retrieve it?

Comment: Might be under `IndexedDB` or `databases` or other directories in the browser profile. Do a search for the extension id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like in the case of the Sense extension, its only persistent data was kept in `localStorage` ([relevant source](https://github.com/bleskes/sense_old/blob/master/src/history.js)).

Whether data recovery will be easy depends heavily on *when* you last used the extension.

1. If you last used the extension before Chrome 61 (~ September 2017), then you are in luck: the `localStorage` database is stored in SQLite 3 format.

   You need to find the corresponding `chrome-extension_[some_id]_0.localstorage` file under `Local Storage` in your profile; it's an SQLite database. The ID doesn't seem to be the same as the extension ID.

   You can load it in various tools, including [sqliteonline.com](https://sqliteonline.com/) for an online browser.
2. If you need data since update to Chrome 61, you're in a much tougher situation. Chrome 61 [switched to LevelDB for `localStorage` backend](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225934), and I couldn't easily extract the data from it.

   See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074659/access-google-chromes-indexeddb-leveldb-outside-of-chrome) for subtleties involved. The database itself is located at `Local Storage/leveldb` in your profile.

   It seems like Chrome does not delete older SQLite-formatted data, so you can recover at least data from early September.

FWIW, the ID of the extension appears to have been `lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig`

Comment: Looks like I can't recover my queries, no .localstorage file in the file directory. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I also lost all my mappings and queries. Never using chrome again..

Answer (score 8):

Please download this [zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjoe4aj35fazzac/sense_chrome_plugin.zip?dl=0) file from my dropbox and follow the instructions to install it. Please run the file through some anti-virus to protect yourself. Thanks to this [link](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/how-to-export-an-installed-extension-chrome/) to help me export chrome extension.

1. List item Download and unzip attachment
2. Go to chrome://extensions
3. Delete the current Sense plugin installed
4. Check developer mode and click on "Load unpacked extension..." and select the unzipped folder.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to get Sense (Beta) working again, unfortunately all my old queries are lost

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your Chrome profile to your ChromiumPortable profile then your Sense extension will be enabled in Chromium with all your history.

Chrome profile
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Chromium Profile (rename existing profile to Default.bak)
C:\ChromiumPortable\Data\Chromium\UserData\Default

I had the same problem and the above fix got me my Sense history.  I am using Chrome 63 and Chromium 65.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Just updated to Chrome 79, this no longer allows me to load addon.

Just updated my Chrome to 69, It disabled my Sense (beta) addon with a "Malware" message, and I thought I lost all my data. The solution is pretty simple.

Go to `chrome://flags/#extension-content-verification` flag settings by setting as `Enforce Strict`, changing it to `Bootstrap`.

This let me load the extension, and all my saved queries were there.

Answer (score -2):

To identify the extension you need to open chrome://extensions/ and check "Developer mode" (on the top right), then scroll down to the extension and you'll find the Extension's ID.
Folder under C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions will be named with Extensions' IDs.

Comment: That doesn't help with data recovery; the folder you mention only contains the extension's files, not persistent data.