# Getting data inside a google Chrome IndexedDB from Bash or Python

Tags: python, bash, google-chrome, indexeddb, leveldb

I have LevelDB (IndexedDB) file from my Google Chrome, the file is located in this folder:

```
/home/<user>/.config/google-chrome/Default/IndexedDB/https_<site>_0.indexeddb.leveldb/
```

The folder content is:

```
$ ls
000005.ldb  000006.log  CURRENT  LOCK  LOG  MANIFEST-000001
```

And I have a very simple python script for opening it:

```
#!/bin/python
import leveldb
db = leveldb.LevelDB('./000005.ldb')
```

Now I always get this error:

```
leveldb.LevelDBError: IO error: ./000005.ldb/LOCK: Not a directory
```

Does anyone have information about how correctly access the data stored in my IndexDB files? Basically, I just need to get the same information like from the 'Developers Tool' view but using Bash or Python.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but worth knowing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074659/how-to-access-google-chromes-indexeddb-leveldb-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to open the directory with this API, not a file. Also it worth noting that using [`plyvel`](https://plyvel.readthedocs.io) library is probably better:

```
import plyvel
db = plyvel.DB('/home/<user>/.config/google-chrome/Default/IndexedDB/https_<site>_0.indexeddb.leveldb')
for key, value in db:
    print("{0} : {1}".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
db = leveldb.LevelDB('./Here must be a folder containing all of the levelDB database files')
```