# Trying to open an indexedDB database and I get this Error: Invalid argument: idb_cmp1 does not match existing comparator : leveldb.BytewiseComparator'

Tags: comparator, indexeddb, opendatabase

I'm trying to open an indexedDB database using Python and I get this error:

> *Error: Invalid argument: idb_cmp1 does not match existing comparator : leveldb.BytewiseComparator*

It seems I have to implement a comparator, but I don't know how to. Is there another solution to this? Or another way to open/view the database?

Comment: indexedDB is intended to be accessed exclusively through javascript and the browser, so you are probably on your own here

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074659/how-to-access-google-chromes-indexeddb-leveldb-files