# How to read IndexedDB files in Chrome folder

Tags: c#, leveldb

I want to access to BDD `indexedDB` files in chrome profil from my WPF app.

I tried to use [LevelDB.NET](https://github.com/oodrive/leveldb.net) but :

sometimes I had an exception *"Corruption: corrupted compressed block contents"* when iterating the rows.

sometimes I were able to iterate, but I can't figure out how the data is encoded/serialized. When I decode the byte arrays to a UTF8 string, I saw a mix of readable strings and random characters.

```
date:\"\2023-10-10T15:21:31.131+0200\"\treferenceo\"\rtype\"\aCONTRAT\"\u000fnumero\"\bAP123456\"\rcode\"\u000201\"\bsource\"\u0003ABC{\u0005\"\achemise0\"\t"\alabel\"\u0014my_contract\{\r{\u0003
```

Exist a reliable solution for connecting to LevelDB pls ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but some clues... Look at [ChromiumDbWrapper](https://github.com/gro-ove/actools/blob/f7355e2b2704e181961e68aa133b451208da11f7/AcTools.LapTimes.LevelDb/ChromiumDbWrapper.cs). You'd have to make a few changes to make it work (like I did), but at least I managed to extract some data, however just very few. If you have more time than I have and you succeed in this path, please share your experience too.

In the ChromiumDbWrapper class, you might want to replace "idb_cmp1" with "leveldb.BytewiseComparator" for a start.

Also see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074659/how-to-access-google-chromes-indexeddb-leveldb-files).

Also see [NitraLeveldb](https://github.com/nitrachain/leveldb). You may want to update it from google/leveldb.